# Creating procedure that add value when it doesn't exist (Syntax error)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that add a value that doesn't exist but I'm currently getting a syntax error. I don't know how to correct the error. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE Name = animalName); END' at line 5


Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUniqueName (In animalName varchar(100) )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Animals (Name)
  SELECT animalName
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Animals WHERE Name = animalName);
END //
    
Delimiter ;
```

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag since SQL Server and MySQL are different products and this code is not SQL Server t-sql.

Comment: SELECT animalName WHERE...is no correct syntax. I don't know what you try do to there, but a where clause requires a preceding from.

Comment: If you want to use WHERE then FROM clause must present.

Comment: Make `Name` column in `Animals` table unique. Use simple INSERT IGNORE, without WHERE. Of add FROM clause: ```.. SELECT animalName FROM (SELECT 1) src WHERE ..```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INSERT IGNORE statement for uniq keys.

let's assume you have a table

```
create table Animals( name varchar(255) unique key);
```

then

```
Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUniqueName (In animalName varchar(100) )
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Animals (Name) values(animalName);
END //
    
Delimiter ;
```